# Optimizing few GB of data in Hadoop Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've been using Hive quite extensively now, and I was wondering if there was a way to improve the following workflow.

Every night, a tab-delimited uncompressed textfile dump from our Oracle cluster is written to HDFS, to be processed by Hive.

I load the table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ACCOUNTINGTABLE (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       ts STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       duid STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       owner STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       hidden STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       lgroup STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       nbfiles INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       length BIGINT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       replicas INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       provenance STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       state STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       campaign STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       rlength BIGINT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       rnbfiles INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       rowner STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       rgroup STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       rarchived STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
       rsuspicious STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
       name STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       ami STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       site STRING)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'                                                                                                                                                                                                
LOCATION '/user/accounting/dump';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/accounting/dump_REPLACEWITHTIMESTAMP.lst' INTO TABLE ACCOUNTINGTABLE;
```

and then run multiple accounting summaries like this to produce text-based output for postprocessing:

```
set hive.exec.reducers.max=90;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ACCOUNTINGTABLE_site_project_datatype_tag (                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ts STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
project STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
datatype STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
tag STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
site STRING,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
duids INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
replicas INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
nbfiles INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
rnbfiles INT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
length BIGINT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
rlength BIGINT)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'                                                                                                                                                                                                
LOCATION '/user/accounting/summary/REPLACEWITHTIMESTAMP/site_project_datatype_tag';                                                                                                                                                                                    

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ACCOUNTINGTABLE_site_project_datatype_tag                                                                                                                                                                                                       
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
'REPLACEWITHTIMESTAMP',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){1}', 1),                                                                                                                                                                                                            
regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){5}', 1),                                                                                                                                                                                                            
split(regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){6}', 1), '_tid')[0],                                                                                                                                                                                          
site,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
count(distinct duid),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
sum(replicas),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
sum(nbfiles),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
sum(rnbfiles),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
sum(length),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
sum(rlength)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
from                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ACCOUNTINGTABLE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
where                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ami='project.datasetnumber.physicsshort.prodstep.datatype.version'                                                                                                                                                                                                     
or                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ami='project.runnumber.streamname.prodstep.datatype.version'                                                                                                                                                                                                           
)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
group by                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
'REPLACEWITHTIMESTAMP',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){1}', 1),                                                                                                                                                                                                            
regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){5}', 1),                                                                                                                                                                                                            
split(regexp_extract(name, '^(?:(?!\2)([^.]*)(?:\.|$())){6}', 1), '_tid')[0],                                                                                                                                                                                          
site;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

DROP TABLE ACCOUNTINGTABLE_site_project_datatype_tag;
```

Now:

The average file size of an Oracle dump is about 5GB (so not really that much), with about 250 million rows. The summaries are not larger than 1-2 MB.

The average Hive job as mentioned above then takes about an hour to run. The mapping phase progresses really well, and is at 100% after about 15 minutes, but then reduce takes almost 45 minutes all the time showing 100%. 
Now we've gradually been adding more and more different summaries and soon we will hit the magic limit of 24 hours for summary processing. Our infrastructure monitoring also shows that the node utilisation is low (cpu ~30-40%, io ~10%).

I've tried playing with io.sort.mb, io.sort.factor, etc... but that almost always made things worse. So now I'm running Hadoop defaults (Cloudera distribution btw). The cluster is 12 nodes (8 core), with 24GB ram and 2TB disk each, configured for 8 mappers, 8 reducers (6/6 on the namenode).

I also tried creating a temporary table as a compressed sequencefile with an INSERT INTO SELECT, but that INSERT just took too long...

I have the suspicion that there might be something wrong with the workflow itself, and not only the cluster/configuration.

Any advice is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Answering my own question:

multi-group-by inserts are the solution. Through some magic it now takes 20 minutes to run the whole accounting suite.

*baffled*

Comment: Well, that was premature. Running the same thing again, it went back to the original runtime.

Comment: What is your network and disk utilization like?

Comment: Network is maxed out... consistently aggregate 60-70MB/s, nodes pumping at their max of 10M/s, which is about the maximum the network can take.

Disk utilisation is rather low however. IO waits are at about 10-20%.

Comment: Try setting mapred.compress.map.output to True. This will compress your map outputs before they go over the network.

Comment: Hmm, that did exactly nothing.

Another observation: the few times where it ran fast it only had a handful of map/reduce phases (10/10), whereas when it's slow it is way more (550/150).

Comment: Is the data size changing? What does your query plan look like?

Comment: I've finally done it in Pig. Does what I want in the expected amount of time. Pity though, I liked Hive.

Comment: I would suspect that it is a difference in how the query plan is optimized.

Comment: Does each of your nodes indeed have a single 2TB disk? If this is the case and the CPU load never goes over 30-40%, your nodes might be waiting for I/O. Adding more spindles should help in this situation.

Comment: It's two 1TB disks in a JBOD. But I think the problem is that the query plan from Hive is just not good enough (and I really don't have the time to debug something like this). If I explicitly state what I want in Pig it works exactly as advertised though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried partitions or indexes

Partition can greatly speed up group by as the data is physically divided over the nodes by partition and therefore the reduce operations are greatly reduced and in some cases instant.

Comment: I have multiple analyses that are orthogonal to many partition schemes, so it wouldn't really help much. And by now, I've done it in Pig.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Partitioning, you can do Bucketing and you can specify Sort By in it.

Check creating Views. That might help too than having table without partitions.